# Rendering differences between NSTextField and NSTextView on a black background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I'm trying to draw text onto a black background and I'm seeing some differences in the way the text is rendered. Here's my code:

```
NSTextView * textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 50.0f)];
[textView setDrawsBackground:YES];
[textView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[textView setString:@"NSTextView: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."];
[textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f]];
[textView setEditable:NO];
[textView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

[flippedView addSubview:textView];

NSTextField * textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 50.0f, 500.0f, 50.0f)];
[textField setDrawsBackground:YES];
[textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[textField setBordered:NO];
[textField setBezeled:NO];
[textField setStringValue:@"NSTextField: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."];
[textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f]];
[textField setEditable:NO];
[textField setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

[flippedView addSubview:textField];
```

The text inside the NSTextField looks great but the text inside the NSTextView looks too bold. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have textField on line 5,6,7?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error!

Answer (score 0):

The NSTextField probably tells its cell about the dark background, which is not what you may want. Tell it to render for light background:

```
[[textField cell] setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLight];
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show the problem. The NSTextField renders the text perfectly. It's the NSTextView that looks 'wrong'.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like this just replace your this line:-

```
//replace below this line
    //[textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f]];
//Modified this below line
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
        NSFont *regular = [fontManager fontWithFamily:@"Helvetica"
                                                  traits:NSUnitalicFontMask
                                                  weight:0
                                                    size:18.0f];
        [textView setFont:regular];
```